# Discord.js-commando: Stopping all commands if not in a specific channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

For testing I am trying to stop all commands, unless in a certain channel. I know how to do this for each command specifically, but I am trying to catch it inside of the main bot file, and return a message. I have tried two ways so far:

```
bot.on('command', async m => { (Also tried 'commandmessage')
  console.log('COMMAND');
  if (m.channel != 'bot-testing') {
    return m.channel.send('You can\'t use commands here!');
  }
});
```

Which doesn't work at all. Then I tried this:

```
bot.on('message', async m => {
    m.isDM = (m.guild ? false : true);
    if (m.content[0] != bot.commandPrefix) {
      return;
    } else {
      if (m.channel != 'bot-testing') {
        m.channel.send('You can\'t use commands here!');
      }
    }
});
```

Which kind of works, but doesn't stop the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were super close - you just need to look at `m.channel.name` in your second `if-statement` (using method #2):

```
bot.on('message', async m => {
    // ...
    if (m.content[0] != bot.commandPrefix) {
        return;
    } else {
        // [NEW: add .name prop here]
        if (m.channel.name != 'bot-testing') {
            m.channel.send('You can\'t use commands here!');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @William haha you're good - I do lots of `console.log` statements to avoid little mistakes like that - maybe that could help you too?

Comment: I usually do. Actually I think I did, figured out what I needed nd I thought Ichanged it. It's been a hell of a weekend I guess.